# Apply aspect on ForkJoinPool method (non-spring managed bean)

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, mdc, forkjoinpool

I want to copy and set MDC context map to thread which is managed by ForkJoinPool in spring application. Unfortunetly I cannot add aop on execute method because ForkJoinPool is non managed spring bean.
I cannot also apply aop on ForkJoinTask.
Do you have any idea how to apply aop on non bean class? Or how I can copy MDC context map to ForkJoinPool?

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Aspect
public class ForkJoinTaskAspect {

    @Around("execution(* java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.execute(..))")
    public Object executionAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
        log.debug("ForkJoinTaskAspect:: Before invoking execute() method");
        Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        Object value = null;
        try {
            MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
            value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            MDC.clear();
        }
        log.debug("ForkJoinTaskAspect:: After invoking execute() method. Return value=" + value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use AspectJ as in the official documentation . [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj)

Answer (score 1):

User [R.G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4214241/r-g) already gave you the right clue, you can only advise classes which are not Spring beans using native AspectJ.

In this case your quest is further complicated by the fact that you wish to weave into a **JRE class on the bootstrap class path,** which is not easily possible with AspectJ. So unless you want to do some rather ugly stuff like binary JRE class weaving and putting the woven JRE classes on the boot class path, I recommend you just weave into your application target classes instead, using `call()` rather than `execution()`. That means you would not weave the callee class `ForkJoinPool` but all the calling classes. Here is a little example:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(() -> {
      System.out.println("Task executed in ForkJoinPool");
    });
    Thread.sleep(100);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.Map;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

@Aspect
public class ForkJoinTaskAspect {
  @Around("call(* java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.execute(..))")
  public Object executionAroundAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
    System.out.println("Before " + proceedingJoinPoint);
    Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    Object value = null;
    try {
      MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
      value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      MDC.clear();
    }
    System.out.println("After " + proceedingJoinPoint);
    return value;
  }
}
```

File `META-INF/aop.xml` would be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="de.scrum_master.aspect.ForkJoinTaskAspect" />
  </aspects>
  <weaver options="-showWeaveInfo">
    <include within="de.scrum_master.app..*" />
  </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

The console log would be:

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-call(void java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.execute(java.lang.Runnable))' in Type 'de.scrum_master.app.Application' (Application.java:7) advised by around advice from 'de.scrum_master.aspect.ForkJoinTaskAspect' (ForkJoinTaskAspect.aj)
Before call(void java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.execute(Runnable))
After call(void java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.execute(Runnable))
Task executed in ForkJoinPool
```

Comment: Great explanation . It didnt occur to me that it was a JRE class